# #{cc} is resolving wrong in omnifaces tree if used in nested composite components

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, composite-component, omnifaces

See the following simplified code:

### test.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:test="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/test">
    <body>
        <h:form>
            <h1>Nested - not working</h1>
            <test:parentComp />

            <h1>Not nested - working</h1>
            <o:tree value="#{testModel.treeModel}">
                <o:treeNode>
                    <ul>
                        <o:treeNodeItem>
                            <test:childComp />
                            <o:treeInsertChildren />
                        </o:treeNodeItem>
                    </ul>
                </o:treeNode>
            </o:tree>
        </h:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

### parentComp.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
      xmlns:test="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/test">
    <cc:interface componentType="parentComp">
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>
        <div id="#{cc.clientId}">
            <o:tree value="#{cc.treeModel}">
                <o:treeNode>
                    <ul>
                        <o:treeNodeItem>
                            <test:childComp />
                            <o:treeInsertChildren />
                        </o:treeNodeItem>
                    </ul>
                </o:treeNode>
            </o:tree>
        </div>
    </cc:implementation>
</html>
```

### childComp.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <cc:interface componentType="childComp">
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>
        <div id="#{cc.clientId}">
            <h:commandLink action="#{cc.childAction}" value="Click" />
        </div>
    </cc:implementation>
</html>
```

### ParentComponent.java

```
@FacesComponent("parentComp")
public class ParentComponent extends UINamingContainer {

    private TreeModel treeModel;

    public ParentComponent() {
        this.treeModel = new ListTreeModel();
        this.treeModel.addChild("1").addChild("1.1");
        this.treeModel.addChild("2").addChild("2.2");
    }

    public TreeModel getTreeModel() {
        return treeModel;
    }
}
```

### ChildComponent.java

```
@FacesComponent("childComp")
public class ChildComponent extends UINamingContainer {

    public void childAction() {

    }
}
```

### TestModel.java

```
@RequestScoped
@Named
public class TestModel {

    private TreeModel treeModel;

    public TestModel() {
        this.treeModel = new ListTreeModel();
        this.treeModel.addChild("1").addChild("1.1");
        this.treeModel.addChild("2").addChild("2.2");
    }

    public TreeModel getTreeModel() {
        return treeModel;
    }
}
```

In the example there the o:tree is used in the composite component, the #{cc} of the child component is resolved wrongly, if you click on the link you will get the an exception like this:

```
Caused by: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /resources/test/childComp.xhtml @10,71 action="#{cc.childAction}": Method not found: ParentComponent@422dcfd4.childAction()
```

If the o:tree is not nested inside a composite component like in the second example, the commandlink is working as intended.

Is this a bug in Omnifaces? Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in OmniFaces. I fixed it in [this commit](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/bfa8d00901a6e2079220f80986675e6c3cb89bf3) and the fix is available in today's 2.3 snapshot (the 2.3 final is expected end this week, so you're pretty on time).

Reason is, the queued action event is basically [caught](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.2/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/component/tree/Tree.java#L185) and [wrapped](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.2/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/component/tree/Tree.java#L552) by `<o:tree>` so that it can remember the currently iterated tree node on which it was fired. However, when broadcasting the action event, it's being invoked on `<o:tree>` itself and not on the source component (your command link). Thus, only the `#{cc}` in the context of `<o:tree>` itself is considered as composite component parent.

I fixed it by [pushing](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#pushComponentToEL-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-javax.faces.component.UIComponent-) the source component's own composite component parent, if any, into EL context.

[Original `Tree#broadcast()` method](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.2/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/component/tree/Tree.java#L261):

```
wrapped.getComponent().broadcast(wrapped);
```

[Fixed `Tree#broadcast()` method](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/bfa8d00901a6e2079220f80986675e6c3cb89bf3/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/component/tree/Tree.java#L261):

```
UIComponent source = wrapped.getComponent();
pushComponentToEL(context, getCompositeComponentParent(source));

try {
    source.broadcast(wrapped);
}
finally {
    popComponentFromEL(context);
}
```

Thank you for reporting!